# Регулярные выражения: найти последнюю цифру в выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript, строки

к примеру имеется строка

```
var str = "17213+3817+29218+34467";
```

как с помощью регулярных выражений найти последнюю цифру (имеется в виду 34467).

Answer (score 3):

Как бы:

```
var str = "17213+3817+29218+34467";

var last_num = str.split('+').slice(-1);
var last_num = str.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

Первый способ конечно же лучше.

Comment: Спасибо, а если вводятся данные, с различными математическими операторами, как в инженерном калькуляторе, как получить последнее число (не цифру)?

Comment: @Pzc вторым способом. Он отрезает последнее число.